# Snap SVG animation loop

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I'm trying to figure out, how to make the entire animation loops with snap SVG. I have 2 step animation with rectangles. For now I have ended up with something like this. Something funny is happening here. Firstly, the animation goes back instead of restarting, and it stops.

```
function firstStep() {
   setTimeout(function () {
     bigRectangle.animate({width:250}, 3000);
     mainFooter.animate({width:250}, 3000);
     leftSidebar.animate({width:40, fill:"#22313F"}, 3000);
     rightSidebar.animate({x:460, width:40, fill:"#22313F"}, 3000);
     mainContent.animate({x:300, width:150}, 3000);
   }, 2000);
   secondStep();
}

function secondStep() {
   setTimeout(function () {
   bigRectangle.animate({width:180}, 2500);
   mainFooter.animate({width:180, y:640}, 2500);
   leftSidebar.animate({width:180, height:50}, 2500);
   rightSidebar.animate({ width:180, height:50, y:580, x:250}, 2500);
   mainContent.animate({x:250, y:170, width:180}, 2500);
   }, 6000);
}

function loopRect(){
   setInterval(firstStep, 8000);
}

loopRect();
```

Comment: Could you give an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/d04gfsx0/1/ ,
The last step of the animation is where all rectangles are vertically equally aligned, then it should restart the animation. It will be imitation of responsive view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two problems:

```
setInterval(firstStep, 3000);
```

This interval doesn't leave enough time for the animation to finish before it starts again.

Also, if you want the animation to restart, you'll have to put everything back where it was. This will require a third step to your animation:

```
setTimeout(function () {
bigRectangle.animate({width: 400}, 2500);
mainFooter.animate({width: 400,y: 520}, 2500);
leftSidebar.animate({width: 70,height: 400,fill: "#19B5FE"}, 2500);
rightSidebar.animate({width: 70,height: 400,y: 110,x: 580,fill: "#19B5FE"}, 2500);
mainContent.animate({x: 330,y: 110,width: 240}, 2500);
}, 10000);
```

Actually, there is no reason why you can't put all the animation code in a single function. [Here's an updated jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/d04gfsx0/2/)

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful :)